# If $M\in BC$ of $\triangle ABC$, and $2\cot \angle AMC =\cot B-\cot C$, then $AM$ is a median

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In $\triangle ABC$, with $M\in BC$ and $\angle AMC=\theta$, if we have 
>   $$2\cot \theta =\cot B-\cot C$$
>   then we may conclude that $AM$ is a median.

My try :

$AH=h$ altitude  , then $BM=x$ and $CM=y$ ,then $MH=z$ , $HC=w$

$CM=CH+HM=x$ so we will prove that $x=y$

$$\cot \theta =\frac{z}{h}$$

$$\cot B=\frac{x+z}{h}$$

$$\cot C =\frac{w}{h}$$

Then from first rotation we concluded !

$2\frac{z}{h}=\frac{x+z-w}{h}$

This mean :

$x-w=z\implies x=w+z\implies x=y$

I'm correct or no !?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative, maybe cleaner, proof. Apply the sine rule to the triangles ABM and ACM,

$$\frac{BM}{CM} = \frac{\frac{BM}{AM}}{\frac{CM}{AM}}
 =\frac{\frac{\sin(\theta-B)}{\sin B}}{\frac{\sin(\theta+C)}{\sin C}}
=\frac{\sin\theta\cot B - \cos\theta}{\sin\theta\cot C + \cos\theta}
=\frac{\cot B - \cot\theta}{\cot C + \cot\theta}=1
$$

Comment: @Quatno very nice thank you very much

Comment: thanks! Can you explain to me in $ABM,ACM$, $\frac{AM}{\sin B}=\frac{AB}{\sin π-\theta }=\frac{BM}{\sin ?}$ ?? Also for triangle $ACM$ how sin rule here ?? You result ??

Comment: @EllenEllen - Note $\angle BAM = \theta - B$. Then, $\frac{AM}{\sin B}=\frac{BM}{\sin\angle BAM} = \frac{BM}{\sin(\theta - B)} $. On the other hand, $\angle CAM = 180 - (\theta + C)$. Then, $\frac{AM}{\sin C}=\frac{CM}{\sin\angle CAM} = \frac{CM}{\sin(\theta + B)} $